# How to optimize or better control my AMD card?

Tags: drivers, radeon, fancontrol, overclocking

I have an RX570, and I was wondering if there were a good way to better optimize how Ubuntu works with it, beyond the built-in driver.

If possible too, would there be a way to control things like fan curve and voltage in a similar way as you can in the normal utility on Windows?

Comment: Referred to fan control, you should check this out: https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc

Answer (score 0):

[HOWTO undervolt the AMD RX 4XX and RX 5XX GPUs](https://linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_undervolt_the_AMD_RX_4XX_and_RX_5XX_GPUs) article describes the settings you want to look at (such as `ppfeaturemask`, `pp_od_clk_voltage`, `pp_dpm_sclk`, etc).

I don't know if there's any GUI tool, a quick google reveals [LACT](https://github.com/ilyazzz/LACT) and [corectrl](https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl) but I have no experience with them so I can't recommend them.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to also include the relevant part of the links you posted. Your answer would be of no value if the links stopped working for some reason.